# Accessing a 2d char array column wise in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was trying to loop over a 2d char array, however I need to access elements in column wise. The problem is that the length of the columns in not fixed, what i mean is for ex. my char array contains this.

```
abcde
kj
m
vghyed
erty
```

Desired ouput:

```
akmve
bjgr
cht
dyy
ee
d
```

I tried all methods, like converting each row into string,for ex. rows in 2d array can be accessed like

```
String mystr = String.valueOf(myChar[i]);
```

Usage of nested loops like this

```
for(j=0;j<c;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        {
            //if(mychar[i][j]!=null)
            {
                System.out.print(mychar[i][j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Gives me

```
akhr 
bjyt 
cmey 
dvd
```

Which is wrong

but is there a way to access a 2d array column wise?

Comment: since a 2d array is basicly an array of arrays your method can only work with the arrays at one dimension. What you might want to do is to build the strings in a nested loop where you can acces them like `[x][y]` or `[y][x]` which will change the way you are creating the string (column or row)

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] strings = new String[5];
int maxLength = //u fond the size of the longest string

for (int i=0; i<maxLength; i++) { //the number of lines u will get
    for (int j=0; i<strings.length; i++) { //for each strings u have
        if(j<strings[i].length)
            print(strings[i].substring(j)
    }
    println;
}
```

No reason u couldnt make it by your own
edit: u actually made it by your own.
Try "System.out.print(mychar[j][i]);" instead

Answer (score 0):

With adding one more variable you could do the following, which is easy but doesn't look this nice:

```
int max = 0;
for (char[] a1 : a) {
    max = max > a1.length ? max : a1.length;
}
```

This was for finding the largest subarray, so you don't get a `NullpointerException`, the following will print your desired output:

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    for (char[] a1 : a) {
        if (i < a1.length) {
            System.out.print(a1[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(); // only for newline
}
```

Or you can mix it up like this:

```
for (int i = 0, max = a[0].length; i < max; i++) {
    for (char[] a1 : a) {
        max = max > a1.length ? max : a1.length;
        if (i < a1.length) {
            System.out.print(a1[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(); // only for newline
}
```

This would erase one loop and the variable ´max´ is only usable in the loops, where it is needed.